# I got stuck in getAssests() in the below code

Tags: android

```
public class XYZ extends LinearLayout{

     TextView text  = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.kid_name);
    Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "eng111.ttf");
    text.setTypeface(font);
}
```

I just try to use the other format for the text and the problem is occurred "create the getAssets() method "

Where do I mistake ? please sort out this problem

Comment: does `LinearLayout` have method `getAssets()`?

Comment: downvoters please suggest me where am I doing mistake ....

Comment: you need a context. getContext().getAssets()

Comment: I am doing sir @Selvin

Comment: `YourActivityName.this.getAssets();` would be more appropriate in order to avoid the memory leak

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a `Context`, since you are not in an `Activity` you need to call:

```
getContext().getAssets();
```

Comment: @user2078315 Why shouldn't you accept this as a correct answer if it is working for you!?